# Utilizar dois webdrives no selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Preciso desenvolver um script para automação de um site. Eu recebo uma lista de `URLs` eu passo esta lista em  um `for` que para cada item da lista se cria um novo `webdriver` e ele pede para fazer login no site. Eu pensei em criar dois script um que faça o acesso ao site e outro para manipular o site.

Minha tentativa de utilizar dois `webdrivers` e fazer o segundo maximizar a janela criada pelo primeiro, sempre sera criado um novo `webdriver` na chamada da função. Caso saibam uma sugestão melhor por favor pode dizer.

```
def teste(browser,link,i):
    browser.execute_script("window.open('"+link+"','new window','width=200, height=100')")
    browser1 = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser1.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[i])
    browser1.maximize_window()
```

Obs: A lista é muito grande, estou utilizando `multithreads` para agilizar o processo.

Comment: Só um login é necessário? Se sim, você pode reutilizar os cookies de um login nas outras instâncias.

Comment: consegui resolver com a sua ideia de utilizar os cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo a ideia de Pedro utilizei os cookies. Para fazer isso criei duas funções a `s_cookies()` e a `l_cookies` a primeira salva os cookies da pagina já logada e carregada e a segunda carrega os cookies para pagina toda vez que ela é acessada.

```
import pickle
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

def s_cookies(self,browser, loc):
    pickle.dump(browser.get_cookies(), open(loc,'wb'))

def l_cookies(self,browser, loc, url=None):
    cookies = pickle.load(open(loc,'rb'))

    url = "https://google.com" if url is None else url
    browser.get(url)
    for cookie in cookies:
        browser.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Obs1: Só funcionou com o `webdriver` do Chrome e como estava com um prazo apertado não quis me aprofundar pq não funcionou no Firefox

Obs2: Recomendo Chamar a Função `l_cookies()` logo depois da instanciar o ´webdriver`